# NavigationView: custom item layout with app:actionLayout how to?

Tags: android, menuitem, navigationview

according to recent Ian Lake post

> And if you haven't looked at NavigationView recently, it actually got
>   quite an update in version 23.1.0 [1] with the addition of
>   app:actionLayout support for custom view support.

How can I use `app:actionLayout` in NavigationView?

Using

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_1"
        android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_item_1"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_test_1"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_2"
        android:title="@string/navigation_drawer_item_2"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_test_1"
        />
</group>
```

with

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">
```

It doesn't work.
It shows the actionLayout on the right side of the item.
Also removing `android:icon` and `android:title` seems not working.

How can i fix it?

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Did you get the solution ? Even I am working with customizing menu item in action layout and it seems to be not working

Comment: Unfortunately I have not yet a solution...I think we should put pur custom recycler view in the NavigationView...

Comment: missing app:showAsAction="always"?

Comment: I've tryed...it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I beat this problem by removing any text from android:title.

NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Menu code (activity_main_drawer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

menu_item_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How is posible change text of counter in Java, in oncreate no change with .setText()

Comment: See this for counter update https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613942/3496570

Comment: @Webserveis - Hope this would help - https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_build_info"
            android:icon="@null"
            android:title="@null"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/layout"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </group>
```

And also make actionLayout's layout as android:layout_width="wrap_content"